# Only output curl result dependent on mime-type

Tags: terminal, images, curl, mime-types

Is it possible to make curl only save the output of `curl -o` if the file is of a certain mime-type?

For example, I might use the following command to download a bunch of images off a server...

`curl -o file_#1.jpg http://wwww.mysite.com/images.php?id=[1-50]`

On that site, it may return text/html if there isn't an image with that ID. Is there any way to filter the curl results so it only saves files of type image/jpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in bash:

```
declare -i i=1
while (( $i <= 50 ))
do
    filename="file_${i}.jpg"
    curl -o ${filename} http://wwww.mysite.com/images.php?id=${i}
    if ! file ${filename} | grep -qi image
    then
      rm -f ${filename}
    fi
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

This loops through all 50 potential images, downloads each, checks if it really is an image and deletes the downloaded file it if isn't.

If your platform has the `seq` command, you can simplify the loop this way:

```
for i in $(seq 50)
do
    filename="file_${i}.jpg"
    curl -o ${filename} http://wwww.mysite.com/images.php?id=${i}
    if ! file ${filename} | grep -qi image
    then
      rm -f ${filename}
    fi
done
```

In newer bash versions, you can also use the `{n..m}` construct:

```
for i in {1..50}
do
    ...
done
```